# SLRUM Script question for batch processing

Tags: python, arrays, bash, sbatch

I am trying to reproduce a bioinformatics workflow hosted at  https://bioinformaticsworkbook.org/dataAnalysis/VariantCalling/freebayes-dnaseq-workflow.html#gsc.tab=0

In step 1 of the workflow, I have made the commands and saved them to a file, bwa.cmds.   The net next step of instructions says to make the following SLRUM scripts and submit.

makeSLURMs.py 1 bwa.cmds
for sub in *.sub; do
sbatch $sub;
done

I tried to type them on command line or saved them to a .sh file and execute it, but was not succcessdul.
Could you please help with clarifying this step  Do I need to load a specific module or simply run it as a python script?
Thank you,
Regards,
GSA

Comment: _Specifically_, what does "not succcessdul" mean?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.